# NPM Workspaces with two or more @prisma/client dependencies

Tags: npm, prisma, npm-workspaces

I have a monorepo setup. It looks something like this:

- project

  - node_modules
  - packages

    - my-first-project

      - prisma

        - schema.prisma
    - my-second-project

      - prisma

        - schema.prisma

So both projects (my-first-project and my-second-project) have @prisma/client installed and get there dependencies from the upper node_modules folder.

The thing is that whenever i change something in my schema.prisma file (e.g. in my-first-project) and run `npx prisma migrate dev --name whatever` it generates all the types and stuff and puts it in the upper node_modules folder. this leads to "type not found" errors on the other project (e.g. my-second-project).

Is there a way to tell npm to keep some dependencies in a separate node_modules folder inside each project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could configure a custom output path to specify the location at which `PrismaClient` should be generated.

Example:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "../src/generated/client"
}
```

And you should be able to import `PrismaClient` like this:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from './generated/client'
```

By generating PrismaClient outside of `node_modules` should solve your issue.

Comment: It is not clear to me from your example where I tell Prisma to build to an alternative location.

Comment: @ThaJay if you mean the `generator client ...` block, that is from the `schema.prisma` file.